# Spring Data JPA get multiple result set

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I try to get the return value using JPA.
But my database Procedure returns multiple results, and JPA only gets the first return value. as the picture shows.
The result I want is the third one, but I only get the first one.
How to get the third one? Thanks.

[Java Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWfs6.png)
[Database Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nlubt.png)

**Entity.java**

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries(
        {
                @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
                        name = "SpringTestProcedure",
                        procedureName = "SpringTestProcedure",
                        parameters = {
                                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "id", type = Test.class),
                                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "firstName", type = Test.class),
                                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "lastName", type = Test.class)
                        }
                )
        }
)

@Table(name = "Users")
public class Test {

public Test() {
}

public Test(Integer id, String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "firstName")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "lastName")
private String lastName;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

}

**Repository.java**

```
 @Repository
public interface SpringTestRepository extends JpaRepository<Test, Integer> {

    @Procedure(procedureName = "SpringTestProcedure")
    public List<Object[]> getEntity(@Param("id") Integer id,
                                    @Param("firstName") String firstName,
                                    @Param("lastName") String lastName);

}
```

**ServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
public class SpringTestServiceImpl implements SpringTestService {

    @Autowired
    private SpringTestRepository springTestRepository;

    @Override
    public Test getEntity(Integer id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        List<Object[]> list = springTestRepository.getEntity(id, firstName, lastName);
        for (Object[] object : list) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(object));
        }
        return null;//springTestRepository.getEntity(id, firstName, lastName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of parameters

```
        parameters = {
                 @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "id", type = Integer.class),
                 @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "firstName", type = String.class),
                 @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "lastName", type = String.class)
        }
```

Change method getEntity

```
@Override
public Test getEntity(Integer id, String firstName, String lastName) {
    List<Test> list = springTestRepository.getEntity(id, firstName, lastName);
    for (Test test : list) {
        System.out.println(test.getId()+" "+test.getFirstName()+" "+test.getLastName());
    }
    return list.get(2);//springTestRepository.getEntity(id, firstName, lastName);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I changed the types of parameters, but I still only can get first result set. How can I get the third one? Thank you so much.